# Prove that $ \displaystyle \bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1}\{x:r_i \leq x \leq r_{i+1}\}=\{x:r_1 \leq x \leq r_n\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $r_1,...r_n$ are real numbers such as $r_1\leq r_2 \leq ... \leq r_n$. Prove that

$$\bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1}\{x:r_i \leq x \leq r_{i+1}\}=\{x:r_1 \leq x \leq r_n\}$$

What I know, is that it is the same as saying that I have to prove that $$\bigcup _{i=1}^{n-1}[r_i,r_{i+1}]=[r_1,r_n]$$

How can I do that?

Comment: Perhaps you want "$\{x : r_1 \leq x \leq r_n\}$" on the right-hand side of the equality in the title and the first display?

Comment: Do you have the condition $n > 1$?  I ask because the equality is false when $n = 1$ -- the (vacuous) union on the left-hand side is empty, but the set on the right-hand side is nonempty.

Comment: @EricTowers I see what you mean, but let's assume that n > 1.

Answer (score 0):

Two steps:

1. Let $x$ be an arbitrary element of the left set, and show that $x$ is also in the right set.
2. Let $x$ be an arbitrary element of the right set, and show that $x$ is also in the left set.

Comment: Say x $\in \bigcup _{i=1}^{n-1}[r_i,r_{i+1}] \Rightarrow x \in [r_i,r_{i+1}] \forall i = \{1,2,...n-1\}.$ And as $r_1 \leq r_2 \leq ... \leq r_n.$ We have that it is $[r_1,r_n].$ Am I right? That'd be one direction

Comment: That is almost correct for one direction. Your $\forall i$ should instead be *for some* $i$.